# Always loop that does not assign the outputs

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am making an average that resets every period on EDA Playground. No errors are displayed on the simulator, Icarus Verilog, but the outputs are continually unassigned (which, of course, is not what I intended).

Here is my design:

```
    module shift
      (
        input [13:0] in,
        input clock,
        output [31:0] sum,
        output [14:0] avg);

      integer reset;
      reg [31:0] sum_reg;
      reg [14:0] avg_reg;

      always @(posedge clock)
        if (reset == 8) begin
          avg_reg = sum_reg >> 3;
          sum_reg = 0;
          reset = 0;
        end else begin
          sum_reg = sum_reg + in;
          reset = reset + 1;
        end

      assign sum = sum_reg;
      assign avg = avg_reg;
    endmodule
```

Here is my testbench:

```
    module shift_tb;
      reg [13:0] in;
      reg clock = 1'b0;
      reg reset;
      wire [31:0] sum;
      wire [14:0] avg;

      shift s
      (
        .in(in),
        .clock(clock),
        .sum(sum),
        .avg(avg));

      integer f;

      initial begin
        for (f = 9000; f < 10000; f = f + 10) begin
          in = f;
          $display("in = %d, sum = %d, avg = %d", in, sum, avg);
        end
      end

      always
        #1 clock = ~clock;
    endmodule
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is `reset` is an `integer` that is initially `x` and stays that way. You need a way of initializing it to 0.

Another problem is your testbench `for`-loop has no delay. You should add `@(nedgedge clk)`

Comment: Thanks @dave_59, but there appears to be something wrong with my `clock` because if I include it in `$display`, then I can see that it does not change. Isn't this the correct implementation of a clock? What is wrong?

Comment: Your clock is not initialized. It starts as 'x' and stays that way. Your simulation waveform window should show that.

Comment: also, you should use non-blocking assignments in your flop

Comment: `clock` is initialized, The problem is with your `for` loop as is has no delays as I said above,

Comment: Okay, I implemented these changes and it worked. Thanks.